# Conjecture: $\sum_ia_ib_i^x=0$ has at most one real root?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider the real equation: $\sum_ia_ib_i^x=0$. $b_i\neq b_j>0$ and $a_i\neq 0$ for all $i,j$. $\sum_ia_i=0$. $x\neq0$.

Conjecture: $\sum_ia_ib_i^x=0$ has at most one non-trivial real root when the equation is non-trivial.

Is it possible to verify it or disprove it by counterexamples?

Comment: What if $a_i=0$ for all $i$?

Comment: What if $\sum_i a_i = 0$ and $b_i = b$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned with the number of real roots, then The Phoenix's upper bound is sharp.

We have the following;

$\textbf{Claim;}$
For $n \geq 2$, suppose $a_{1},...,a_{n} \neq 0$ and $b_{1},...,b_{n} > 0$ are such that $b_{i} \neq b_{j}$ for $i \neq j$,then

$$S_{n}(x;a_{1},b_{1},...,a_{n},b_{n}) := \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}^{x}$$

has at most $n-1$ distinct real roots in $x$. Furthermore for each $v \neq 0$, the equation $S_{n}(x;a_{1},b_{1},...,a_{n},b_{n}) - v = 0$ has at most $n$ distinct real roots in $x$.

$\textbf{Proof:} $ We use proof by induction.

For $n = 2$, with the above coefficient restrictions, the equation $a_{1}b_{1}^x + a_{2}b_{2}^x =0$ has not more than one real solution in $x$. If for $v \neq 0$ the equation $$a_{1}b_{1}^x + a_{2}b_{2}^x = v$$

has some $r$ solutions, then by Rolle's theorem $$\ln(b_{1})a_{1}b_{1}^x + \ln(b_{2})a_{2}b_{2}^x = 0$$
has at least $r-1$ solutions in $x$, thus $r-1 \leq 1$ or $r \leq 2$. The case $n=2$ is covered.

Suppose that our claim holds for $n=k$.

For $n=k+1$, note that (with the coefficient restrictions)

$$S_{k+1}(x;a_{1},b_{1},...,a_{k},b_{k},a_{k+1},b_{k+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_{i}b_{i}^{x}$$

if the above quantity is to be $0$, then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}(\frac{b_{i}}{b_{k}})^x + a_{k+1} = 0$$

Note that all $\frac{b_{i}}{b_{k}}$ are distinct from one another, thus the above equation has at most $k$ distinct solutions in $x$ (real).

Now if for some $v \neq 0,$ the equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_{i}b_{i}^{x}= v$$
has some $h$ solutions in $x$, then by Rolle's theorem

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\ln(b_{i})a_{i}b_{i}^{x} = 0$$

has at least $h-1$ solutions. Note from above discussion that $h-1 \leq k \Rightarrow h \leq k+1$. This concludes our inductive step, and hence our proof by induction.